# Does Firestore's 500 writes/second limit apply to updates to non-sequential fields in documents with indexed sequential fields?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Let's say we have the following database structure:

```
[collection]
  <documentId>
    - indexedSequentialField
    - indexedNonSequentialField
    - nonIndexedSequentialField
```

Firestore's 500 writes/second limit will apply to the **creation** of new documents if `indexedSequentialField` is there during the creation. Similarly, Firestore's 500 writes/second limit should also apply to any **updates** to the documents that change `indexedSequentialField` because that involves rewriting the index entry. This part is clear.

My understanding is that this limit comes from writing the index entries and not to the collection itself.

If that's true, would it be correct to say that making more than 500 **updates** per second to the documents that change only the `indexedNonSequentialField` or `nonIndexedSequentialField` is fine as long as the `indexedSequentialField` is **not** changed, even if the `indexedSequentialField` is already present in the documents and the index entries since their creation?

For the sake of this question, please assume that there are no composite indices present that end up being sequential in nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore's hotspots on writes occur when it needs to write data from multiple write operations close to each other on disk, as it needs to synchronize those writes across multiple data centers while also isolation each write from each other (since its write operations are immediately consistent).

If your collection or collection group has an index with sequential fields, that will trigger a hotspot indeed. Note that the [limit of 500 writes per second](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#soft_limits) is a **soft** limit, and you may well be able to write much more than that before hitting a hotspot. Nowadays I recommend using the [Key Visualizer](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/key-visualizer) to analyze the performance of your writes.

Comment: So will updates (not creates) that change only the `indexed-nonSequential-field` or `nonIndexed-sequential-field` and don't change the preexisting `indexed-sequential-field` at all also trigger a hotspot?

Comment: If the server will have to write multiple values in close proximity it is subject to hotspot. If you're not touching the sequential field it should not, but use the Key Visualizer to see "exactly" hope the writes are being processed.

Comment: Makes sense.
Just to ensure that I understand you correctly – "server will have to write multiple values in close proximity" is about writing to the index entries and not the collection themselves, right?
And since the rest of the document data isn't stored in the index entry, as long as the index entry is unchanged, any other changes won't trigger the hotspot, correct?

Comment: Sequential'ish document IDs might be the only other case for hotspotting that I can think of.